# Excel Vlookup on multiple values combined with sum or countif

Tags: excel, vlookup, array-formulas

I have 4 columns of codes, and another table that basically says that "group" the code falls into.  Like so:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
1  0  2  3
2  3  4  5 
3  4  2  0
```

The second table is

> code group
>       1    a
>       2    a
>       3    a
>       4    b
>       5    b

I want to add a column next to C4 that will sum or count all of the values that are part of Group a.  I tried doing

```
{=sum(if(vlookup({1,0,2,3},code:group,2,false)="a",1,0))}
```

but it doesn't work (the 1,0,2,3 is just to simulate selecting the first row of data from table 1).

Any ideas how I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have two named ranges `Code` and `Group` try this array* formula in the first row and fill down:

`=SUM(--(IFERROR(LOOKUP(A1:D1,Code,Group)="a",0)))`

*Commit the formula by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think to use just "Lookup"